# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to load css background images on page load but I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

```
function loadBG() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("img-icon-invite").style.background = "url('<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/style/home/images/firstProPopup-sprite-new-white.png')";
    document.getElementsByClassName("img-icon-verified").style.background = "url('http://dev1.venturepact.com/themes/adminre/style/home/images/firstProPopup-sprite-new-white.png')";
}

window.onload = loadBG();
```

Comment: share html as well

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` fetches array of values as you see in its name `getElements`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you need to access each element by its index.

Answer (score 3):

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns array of elements, You need to specify the index too,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("img-icon-invite")[0].style.background="url('<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/style/home/images/firstProPopup-sprite-new-white.png')";
```

Or with Jquery you can do,

```
$(".img-icon-invite").css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned jQuery:

```
function loadBG(){
        $(".img-icon-invite").css('background-image', "url('<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/style/home/images/firstProPopup-sprite-new-white.png')";
        $(".img-icon-verified").css('background-image',"url('http://dev1.venturepact.com/themes/adminre/style/home/images/firstProPopup-sprite-new-white.png')";

}
$(document).ready(loadBG);
```